# Configuring Outlook Webpart in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, outlook, moss, web-parts

I'm exploring sharepoint a bit. I would like to show the email inbox and calendar of the user logged in. The logging in of defferent users is no problem. We are running Exchange 2003 and we're using the webaccess. This works without any problems also.

I added the OWACalendarPart to the default.aspx page. When I set *mail server address* to our mail server. I have to set the mailbox to something. When I enter my mailbox it show my mailbox, but for every user that signs in. They have to enter the credentials thought and I don't. When I enter a **'?'** the control shows the entire outlook web interface instead of only the calendar. In this case the control is for each user with their data.

Am I missing something here? What's the use of this webpart when I have to configure it for every single user? How I can make the calendar show the data for the current sharepoint user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but that's the default behavior, MS expects users to only add the webpart by themselves on for instance their MySite. It is possible to do this though:

most people use a wrapper webpart / control to display the OWA webpart for the current user, here the code for mine:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
  try
  {
    //Create the instance of My Inbox Web Part 
    OWAInboxPart inbox = new OWAInboxPart
    {
       MailboxName = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Email,
       OWAServerAddressRoot = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServer"]
    };

    Controls.Add(inbox);
  }
  catch(Exception)
  {
    Controls.Add(new Literal{Text = "bla"});
  }
}
```